# SQL Server Database is not updated via C# Code

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I am performing record update operation . my update operation is happening fine but database is not updating values . below is update code.

```
        SupPartEntityVal supplypart = new SupPartEntityVal();

        String sNum = sNumText.Text;
        String sName = sNameText.Text;
        String sStatus = sText.Text;
        String sCity = cText.Text;
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(rIndex.Text);

        ObjectQuery<S> supply = supplypart.S;
        var query =
        from product in supply
        select new { product.SNUM, product.SNAME, product.STATUS, product.CITY };
        S sup = supplypart.S.Single(product => product.SNUM == sNum);
        sup.SNAME = sName; sup.STATUS = short.Parse(sStatus); sup.CITY = sCity;

        this.supplypart.SaveChanges();
```

1. After making changes, I can see updated value on UI
2. After I close an application, reopen again I can see updated value on UI
3. Close Visual studio, reopen the application and run it again.
4. I do not see changes in database.

am i missing something???

Comment: I bet your database is in the project, as a content file which is copied to output directory each time you compile

Comment: yes, Steve you are correct my database is in content file as part of project. but If i remove from it, I can not able to run it..

Comment: what's kind of database? Winform, asp.net, WPF? I mean, Sql user instance (or local DB) versus classic sql instance

Comment: I figured it out Go to property of database. (databaseName.mdf) by double clicking it from right solution panel 
change Copy to Output Directory=Copy if newer..

Comment: @user1546784, you should make your comment an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Check Your Record When Saving In Database through Select Query on Command.. And See That is record is Saving? If Yes.. Then Issue is in your Database ... Normally this occurs when we use OLEDB that is Storing Database in project,,,